# Spring | JPA | Hibernate - Returns only 1000 entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new in Java Web Development and for last several days I've been having a big problem, I can not make JPA/Hibernate to return more than 1000 entities.

In my database I have around 1600 `Assortment` entities but whatever I try, I can't get more than 1000 of them, even when I try to count them so I would be able to paginate requests, `COUNT(...)` returns 1000.

I know that problem is not on database server because I've already made PHP server side scripts that work flawlessly with this SQL server.

I've tried using Query, NativeQuery and Criteria. But nothing returns more than 1000 entities.

I'm sure I googled everything, and really do not have any idea what else to do, please help.

My code is below and thank you in advance!

**spring-context.xml**

```
...

<!-- SQL Server Datasource with Commons DBCP connection pooling -->
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://XXX;database=XXX;user=XXX;password=XXX;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
    <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="1000" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

...
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="...">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**AssortmentService.java**

```
@Transactional
public List<Assortment> getWholeAssortment() {

    String searchQuery = "SELECT a FROM Assortment a";

    List<Assortment> result = entityManager.createQuery(searchQuery, Assortment.class).getResultList();

    return result;
}

@Transactional
public int getAssortmentCount(){

    String searchQuery = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_assortment";

    int result = (Integer) entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery).getSingleResult();

    return result;
}

@Transactional
public List<Assortment> getAssortmentWithCriteria(){
    CriteriaQuery<Assortment> criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Assortment.class);
    criteria.select(criteria.from(Assortment.class));
    List<Assortment> result = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If your native query returns 1000 then I suspect you don't have 1600 rows in _that_ database. :)

Comment: Aaand that's what happens when you are inexperienced and trust everyone else. I've just tried with PHP script and this data table and returns 1000 rows, guys who work on database obviously haven't made right test copy.
Thank you, thank you very very very much !

Comment: Was this a situation like sending your electrical helper to the truck for the wire stretcher?